# External url to open in webview

Tags: ios, cordova

My phonegap application exits webview and loads safari browser whenever 'window.location' is called.
I seareched this problem and seems I can fix this problem by changing preference value of config.xml
 in phonegap 1.8

I've tried to find config.xml but can not find one. I am using phonegap 2.1.

where can I find config.xml? or... is there any way stay in webview on phonegap 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phonegap application open Cordova.plist file and enable Setting

```
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES.
```

This will solves that problem.

Comment: oh my... didn't I accept this as answer? thx for the answer. It solved my problem.